# Update method in SpriteKit doesn't update time propely

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, game-loop

i want to count in seconds if i implemented the method in the update method it only works for the first second then it keeps printing number non stop without waiting for one second before printing the next number;
i don't understand why this is happening

```
 -(void) countinSeconds{
            SKAction *count = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];

            SKAction *time = [SKAction runBlock:^{
                    timex++;
                       }];
            SKAction *print = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"%i",timex);
            }];
            [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[count,time,print]]];



        }
        -(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

                    [self countinSeconds];

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use actions for this; the `update:` method is passed the current time, so it's simply a matter of remembering when you started and doing some simple maths:

```
@implementation YourClass () {
    BOOL _started;
    NSTimeInterval _startTime;
    NSUInteger _lastLogTime;
}
@end

@implementation YourClass

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if (!_started) {
        _startTime = currentTime;
        _started = YES;
    } else {
        NSUInteger elapsedTime = (NSUInteger)(currentTime - _startTime);
        if (elapsedTime != _lastLogTime) {
            NSLog(@"Tick: %lu", elapsedTime);
            _lastLogTime = elapsedTime;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks it works but i want to make it every second only i tried casting it to an int but the result is 1111111,222222 and so on

Comment: @MohamedAbouGhazala Making what every second?

Comment: the printing function

Comment: one more thing please if i wanted to add   if (_lastLogTime %2==0) {
        [self addCharacter :self.size atPosition:CGPointMake(100, 150)];
        

}
every 2 seconds for example it doesn't work it adds it without stopping

Comment: @MohamedAbouGhazala You should really ask a new question for that.

Comment: could u plase check my lastest question about the collisions

Answer (score 1):

And here is how you can do it with SKAction:

You don't want to run that method in update: , but rather somewhere else, like in didMoveToView:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
   [self countinSeconds];
}
```

Also you don't need two blocks for this:

```
-(void) countinSeconds{


    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];

    SKAction *print = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        timex++;
         NSLog(@"%i",timex);
    }];


     [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[wait,print]]] withKey:@"counting"];



}
```

To stop the timer you can remove at any time an action associated with "counting" key, like this:

```
if([self actionForKey: @"counting"){[self removeActionForKey:@"counting"];}
```

Comment: it only works for the first second it prints the first second only as did move to view will be evaluated once

Comment: Ah, okay...I forgot to repeat sequence forever...You can check out the edit.